# Thick triangulated subcategory in non-abelian case

Tags: derived-categories, triangulated-categories

A full triangulated subcategory $\mathcal{S}$
of a triangulated category $\mathcal{T}$
is called thick (or épaisse) iff it is closed under extensions
(https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/thick+subcategory).

If a category is abelian then it has notion of
exact sequences and its clear now how to rephrase
it in mor familar homological algebra notion:
If $A, B, C \in \mathcal{T}$ are objects and

$$  A \to B \to C $$

is exact, then thickness says that if
$A, C \in \mathcal{S}$ then $B \in \mathcal{S}$

What about the case when $\mathcal{T}$ is not abelian
and we therefore the exact sequences are not defined
there.
Does the definition of thickness in that case reads
as follows: Let $A, B, C \in \mathcal{T}$ and

$$  A \to B \to C $$

such that $A \to B$ is mono in pure categoretical sense
(notice that notion $0 \to A \to B$ makes no sense
in non-abelain cat).

Then if $A, C \in \mathcal{S}$ then $B \in \mathcal{S}$.
Is it a correct definition or should we impose
more on $  A \to B \to C $, like adiitionally that
$B \to C $ is epi? Or is $A \to B$ mono really
the only assumpion we should impose in non-abelian case?

What about the special case when $\to A \to B \to C \to \Sigma A \to ...$ form a distinguished triangle? Does it play in the definition of thick subcategory the same role as exact sequences in abelian case? More precisely can we apply the definition of thickness above to every subsequence of the distinguished triangle consisting of three subsequent members?

Comment: Despite what it says on the nLab, what you describe in the first paragraph is not the usual definition of a thick subcategory of a triangulated category.

Comment: Possibly you refer to this one: if $a \oplus b \in \mathcal{S}$, then $a,b \in \mathcal{S}$?

Comment: Yes. $\,\,\,\,$

Comment: The definition on the nLab has now been corrected.